# Gradlew vs mvn timezone

Tags: java, gradle, maven-3

I got a Docker container by default in UTC Timezone (gitlab runner)

When i start my tests in the container with "mvn" then jvm uses UTC timezone, but when i start the same tests with "gradelw" then jvm uses the host machine TimeZone.

Is there any difference between mvn and gradlew how they start jvm timezone point of view?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a setting somewhere in your `pom.xml` or the way how you run it. Actually, there could be a lot of ways it works in UTC in Maven.

Try running Gradle with the `user.timezone` property: `./gradlew test -Duser.timezone=GMT`. That is probably the easiest way to validate the setup.